# a lemma on interval translation map

Tags: gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, translation, discrete-dynamical-systems

Consider the map $S:T^1 \to T^1$ where $x \mapsto x+c_j$ ,  mod 1 where $c_j$'s are real numbers. We represent $T^1$ as a union of disjoint subsegments $M_j=[t_j,t_{j+1})$, $j=0 , \cdots ,n , t_0=t_n$. in the above map $t \in M_j$.

Define $H:=\bigcup_{j=1}^n \partial M_j$ and $\Omega:=\bigcup_{k \geq 0}S^{-k}(H)$.

I want to prove this lemma:

For this map i.e $S:T^1 \to T^1$ where $x \mapsto x+c_j$, mod 1 where $c_j$'s are rational numbers all points of $T^1 \setminus \Omega$ is eventually periodic.

> My try: If $x \in T^1 \setminus \Omega$ then $x \notin \Omega$ so $x \notin \bigcup_{k \geq 0}S^{-k}(\bigcup_{j=1}^n \partial M_j)$ and hence $x \notin  \bigcup_{k \geq 0}\bigcup_{j=1}^nS^{-k}( \partial M_j$) that means $\forall k \geq 0 , j=1 , \cdots ,n \quad x \notin S^{-k}(\partial M_j)$

I don't know how to continue this...

Comment: What makes you think the lemma is true?

Comment: Its in a published paper.. I was checking

Comment: @AnthonyQuas For a rational rotation like the above lemma we know that the orbit of any point is periodic.

Comment: Do you know anything about the periods of these points?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas In rational rotation map we have this :

$S(x) = x + \frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $q \neq 0$ so $S^q(x)=x+q\frac{p}{q}$ mod 1 so $S^q(x)=x$ and the period is $q$.

Comment: This question is really not suitable for this site (it really smells like a homework question). My suggestion would be to consider which places in $[0,1)$ you can get to by adding the various $c_j$'s.

Comment: @RezaYaghmaeian: If I understand correctly, you define $S$ by $S(z) = z \, \mathrm e ^{2 \pi \mathrm i c_j}$, but where does the $j$ come from? It doesn't make sense, there should be just $c$ instead of $c_j$ - providing that I understand you correctly.

Comment: @AlexM. Each $M_j$ has special $c_j$

For example $c_1$ for elements of $M_1$ and $c_2$ for elements of $M_2$ and ...

Comment: @AlexM. Here we face a rational rotation map. (orientation preserving) so if you know all points of such a map are periodic from the same order. I think this would be a good answer to this question.

Comment: @RezaYaghmaeian: Ah, I see, then the sentence *"We represent $T^1$ as a union [...]"* should have been placed at the beginning of the question, before the definition of $S$.